# How to redirect from on url to another url in Oracle Http Server (OHS)

Tags: oracle, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, server

I am using `OHS`, now I would like to redirect one `url` to another `url`, I am using this configure in `httpd.conf`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://<server>.<domain>:<OHS_PORT>/newhtml.html [R,L]
```

but still now working, anyone used to do? please help to guide me .